# Why label is not getting wrapped inside div?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4, frontend

I want the label inside the bootstrap column `div` get wrapped if text width increases above the div length. Below is my **html** for the issue:

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-4">
    <label>Long Text goes here</label>
  </div>

  <div class="col-1">
    <label>A</label>
  </div>
</div>
```

Below is the screenshot for the error:

[image: img]

The red squared text is the original long text under the Product column and the green squared texts are the text for the columns Flat, Round.

I had tried using `white-space: nowrap` for `label` still did not work .
Any idea why this is happening?

Comment: That product name is a single word, like `kjdkdshfkjsdhfjdbdsjkfhsjklfhsalfjkshdfsflssddddddddhhhhhhhhhhhddddlhkds`  change the name to something like this. `kjdk dshf kjsdhfjdb dsjkfhsjklfhsalfj kshdfsflssdd ddddddddd dddddd ddddd ddd lhkds`.

Comment: If you will notice the long word switched lines.

Answer (score 0):

Can you please check the below code? Hope it will work for you. If there is no space in between the words then you need to apply, `word-break` property in the `label`.

If there is space between words then it works automatically.

Please refer to this link:
https://jsfiddle.net/yudizsolutions/5cqof0a1/1/

```css
label {
  word-break: break-word;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-giJF6kkoqNQ00vy+HMDP7azOuL0xtbfIcaT9wjKHr8RbDVddVHyTfAAsrekwKmP1" crossorigin="anonymous">


<div class="row">
  <div class="col-4">
    <label>kjdkdshfkjsdhfjdbdsjkfhsjklfhsalfjkshdfsflssddddddddhhhhhhhhhhhddddlhkdskjdkdshfkjsdhfjdbdsjkfhsjklfhsalfjkshdfsflssddddddddhhhhhhhhhhhddddlhkds</label>
  </div>

  <div class="col-1">
    <label>A</label>
  </div>
</div>
```